# SQL Server - modifying primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started taking a SQL class, and for a problem the professsor wants us to "Write the SQL that will add 1 to every employee ID (intEmployeeID, it's the PK of the table) in the TEmployees table". There is a foreign key constraint to the table TEmployeeParkingSpots, and she explicitly stated that we shouldn't need to use UPDATE or DELETE, and I am at a loss.

Comment: Hint:  `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Comment: select intEmplpyeeID +1 from TEmployees

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is more advanced that where I'm at right now, but thanks for the input. Hadi I don't see how that works withtout violating the foreign key constraint.